# Firebase Auth UI - Show SignUp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using the Firebase Auth UI for my Angular project.
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#demo

By default the auth buttons names are "Sign In With X, Sign In With Y", etc.

Is there any way to customize these to show "Sign Up With X", etc when a user is on the sign up screen versus when they are on the sign in screen?

Always showing Sign In with X seems to be a bit confusing with a user is on the Sign Up screen.

Answer (score 0):

All the source code is available [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web).  You can make it do whatever you want.

Though, I think you should consider not doing it, as a user might be installing your app on a second device, or simply re-installing it, already have an account, and might not be "signing up" for the first time any more.  FirebaseUI doesn't (and can't) draw a distinction between those cases.  The user is either signed in  or not.

Comment: OP is using FirebaseUI for web, so you might want to give the link for that platform :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Doh.